# MKPolyline boundingMapRect Insets

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

How to add insets to `boundingMapRect` of `MKPolyline` to use it with `MKMapSnapshotter`?

```
    let polyLine = MKPolyline(coordinates:locations , count: locations.count)

    var region = MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect(polyLine.boundingMapRect)
    mapSnapshotOptions.region = region

    mapSnapshotOptions.scale = UIScreen.main.scale
    mapSnapshotOptions.size = imageViewRect.size

    mapSnapshotOptions.showsBuildings = true
    mapSnapshotOptions.showsPointsOfInterest = true

    let snapShotter = MKMapSnapshotter(options: mapSnapshotOptions)
    snapShotter.start { (snapshot, error) in
     //use snapshot
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add span to the region like so:

```
// This will add a 10% increase in the span.
var region = MKCoordinateRegion(polyLine.boundingMapRect)
region.span.latitudeDelta = 1.1
region.span.longitudeDelta = 1.1
```

Edit:

This is also an alternative:

```
let region = polyLine.boundingMapRect
map.setVisibleMapRect(region, edgePadding: UIEdgeInsets(top: 50.0, left: 50.0, bottom: 50.0, right: 50.0), animated: true)
```

Comment: No, delta's type is coordinate degree. And from docs: `Unlike longitudinal distances, which vary based on the latitude, one degree of latitude is always approximately 111 kilometers (69 miles)`

Comment: @Desdenova but wouldn't the span then still be a 10% increase from the total span?

Comment: this is not working! it is making the region so much bigger than needed, and changing deltas does not make things better..

Comment: @AymenHARRATH I added another alternative for you

Comment: @AymenHARRATH, did you try my latest suggestion? :)

Comment: He specifically asked for `MKMapSnapshotter` and not a `MKMapView`. The second option does not help here as it requires a `MKMapView`.